# Suppress Javadoc Warnings in Android project with Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, javadoc, lint

I got some troubles with javadoc warnings. When I push my commits and create a pull request in my GitHub repository a Lint Code Base test runs and then shows in the console that a lot of methods and classes do not have a Javadoc comment like below:

> Missing a Javadoc comment. [JavadocVariable]

I need to suppress all the Javadoc warnings, but I can't and I tried different ways. My research took me to many threads about this topic, but I did not find any solution to solved my problem.

I tried adding:

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    options.addBooleanOption('Xdoclint:none', true)
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xdoclint:none"
}
```

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }
```

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }
}
```

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xdoclint:none"
    }
}
```

But no one couldn't suppress the javadoc warnings.

All of these lines of code where inside `allprojects` method.

At this point my build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google() // Google's Maven repository
        jcenter()
    }

    //
    tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        failOnError false
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        options.addBooleanOption('Xdoclint:none', true)
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xdoclint:none"
    }

    tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }

    subprojects {
        tasks.withType(Javadoc).all { enabled = false }
    }

    subprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xdoclint:none"
        }
    }
}
```

=== UPDATE ===

As the first answer says and recommends I created a checkstyle.xml file in the root of my project. The content of checkstyle.xml is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <!-- Javadoc -->
        <!-- Configuración para permitir comentarios Javadoc faltantes en JavadocVariable -->
        <module name="JavadocVariable">
            <property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="true" />
        </module>

        <!-- Configuración para permitir comentarios Javadoc faltantes en JavadocMethod -->
        <module name="JavadocMethod">
            <property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="true" />
        </module>

        <!-- Configuración para permitir comentarios Javadoc faltantes en JavadocPackage -->
        <module name="JavadocPackage">
            <property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="true" />
        </module>

        <!-- Formatting -->
        <module name="LineLength">
            <property name="max" value="160" />
        </module>
    </module>
</module>
```

and in gradle added this:

The plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}
```

The Task:

```
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '8.42'
    configFile = file("${rootDir}/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
}
checkstyleMain {
    source = 'src/main/java'
}
checkstyleTest {
    source = 'src/test/java'
}
```

But the warnings still showing after the Lint Code Base of GitHub Actions runs.

Comment: I did not recommend you create a CheckStyle XML file, I said you needed to _"remove it [the JavadocVariable rule] from your CheckStyle XML config"_. So if you created a new CheckStyle XML config, then that is not going to solve your problem. You need to find the **already existing** CheckStyle config that is in use and modify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that these aren't warnings from the javadoc linter, so configuring or disabling the javadoc tool is not going to help you. The message *"Missing a Javadoc comment. [JavadocVariable]"* is a CheckStyle warning, so you have CheckStyle running, and its profile is configured to require javadoc on all variables (actually, fields).

Given CheckStyle isn't listed in your Gradle file, you probably run it from a GitHub Action (or your build.gradle is not complete).

As far as I'm aware, the *JavadocVariable* rule is not enabled by default, so to disable it, remove it from your CheckStyle XML config.

Based on the [CheckStyle documentation](https://checkstyle.org/checks/javadoc/javadocvariable.html), the rule looks something like this:

```xml
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocVariable"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

Searching for `name="JavadocVariable"` and removing the specific module is likely the best way to deal with this.

Comment: Hi, i didnt have any checkstyle file but i created in app/etc/checkstyle folder and added this a JavadocVariable module and inside ir added `<property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="true" />` but it still showing in the console the _"Missing a Javadoc comment. [JavadocVariable]"_ and also tried to comment that module but the problem persist

Comment: @Alfito69420 It's been a while since I touched CheckStyle, so I'm not sure, but as far as I'm aware from the docs I linked, the `JavadocVariable` rule doesn't have an `allowMissingJavadoc` property (and it wouldn't make sense if it had, because you'd essentially add a rule which requires javadoc, and then say it is not required). You're probably using some default rule set from the classpath or something. I think you need to look at your GitHub Actions definitions for this.

Comment: @Alfito69420 Or in other words, if you didn't already have a CheckStyle task in your Gradle file to begin with (as suggested by you saying you added things), then the failure isn't coming from Gradle, but from a CheckStyle executed by a separate GitHub Action. Check the `.github/workflows` of your repository.

Comment: After making a lot of tries i achieved to supress my warnings, thanks man!